# Bootstrap- jQuery AJAX showing "alert alert-danger" class on both error & success msg

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and using jQuery AJAX to send form data. Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({ 
    type: $(form).attr('method'),
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.type = "error") {
            $('#msgs').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+response.text+"</div>");
            } else {
            $('#msgs').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+response.text+"</div>");
        }
    }
 });
```

That should display error message with **alert alert-danger** class if **type** is **error** in json data & with **alert alert-success** if **type** is **success** in json data. But it displays both error and success messages with **alert alert-danger**.

What's wrong?

Comment: You have used `response.type = "error"` which assigned value `error` into `response.type`. For equality check you should use `==` or `===`, respectively. Shibby answered your question correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to check like this in the if:

```
if (response.type == "error") {
    $('#msgs').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+response.text+"</div>");
} else {
    $('#msgs').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+response.text+"</div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this helper function , you can pass the message with the type of ('danger','success','info','warning') for it .
it will generate bootstrap alert box for you .

```
    var bsMSG = function (msg, type, seprator) {
        html = '';
        msg = (msg instanceof Array ?msg:[msg]);
        type = type || 'success';
        seprator = seprator || '<br/>';
        b = '';
        for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
            html += b + msg[i];
            b = seprator;
        }
        html = "<div class='alert alert-" + type + "'>" + html + "</div>";
        return html;
    };

    // usage

    if (response.type == "error") {
        $('#msgs').html(bsMSG(response.text,'danger'));
    }else{
        $('#msgs').html(bsMSG(response.text'));
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Its better way , also you can pass array of messages to "bsMSG" function .